# Stop the thread and make it run on button click;

Tags: java, swing

Good day every one, i have such situation :

```
SomeDocument doc = DocumentsContainner.getDocument(doc);   
try { 
    DocumentUtitlites.parseDocument(doc);
 } catch (DocumentParseException e) { 
          ManualParsingFrame frame = new ManualParsingFrame(doc);
          frame.show();
 }
NextStageOfUsingDoc(doc);
```

ManualParsingFrame is frame where user can see doc text and parsing in manually by selecting text .It's appear as u can see only when parseDocument(SomeDocument doc) throw exception. When user ends manually parsing text he click ok button wich is on frame.
And start NextStageOfUsingDoc - some other staff that can be processed only if doc was parse by parseDocument or by user ManualParsingFrame. **The question is How to make invoke NextStageOfUsingDoc when user click ok button. Now if i have exception i see frame, but process is continue execution and in result i have visible frame and NextStageOfUsingDoc invoked with non parsed doc object.** Thank u for your time.

Comment: `yourButton.addActionListener(new AtionListener() { public void actionPerformed(Event e) { NextStageOfUSingDoc(doc)}});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a JFrame for this. Show your manual parsing info in a ***modal*** JDialog. This will stop program flow in the calling program until the modal dialog has been dealt with.

Comment: yes you are right, i don't know why i don't think about modal.
thank you.